# Android : Alarm for update more widget

Tags: android, widget, alarm

I use an AlarmManager for update every second a widget but when add more widget only the last widget is updated. I don't understend why...

This is the code...

```
public class widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
        SharedPreferences preference = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,vampireServiceWidget.class);
        context.startService(intent);
        for(int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length;i++){        
            if(preference.getLong("countdown", 0)!=0){
                //Parte il countdown
                Intent in = new Intent().setAction("it.android.dev.thevampirediaries.UPDATE_COUNTDOWN");
                in.putExtra("id_widget", appWidgetIds[i]);
                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1000, pi); 

                    }       }

}
```

into the broadcast this code

```
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widgett);
         thisWidget=intent.getIntExtra("id_widget", 0)
            SimpleTimeFormat tf = new SimpleTimeFormat("$dd$ : $HH$: $mm$: $ss$");    
            String risultato = tf.format(countdown_data_fine - new Date().getTime()); // arg0 tempo
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, titolo_puntata);
            remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2, risultato);
            manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteView);
```

Comment: Official recommendations strongly discourage updating that often, or battery life may suffer a lot. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out the for loop and do not send the widget ids. Use [public void updateAppWidget (ComponentName provider, RemoteViews views) to update the widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget%28android.content.ComponentName,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29).

Try this

```
public class widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
        SharedPreferences preference = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,vampireServiceWidget.class);
        context.startService(intent);
        //for(int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length;i++){        
            if(preference.getLong("countdown", 0)!=0){
                //Parte il countdown
                Intent in = new   Intent().setAction("it.android.dev.thevampirediaries.UPDATE_COUNTDOWN");
                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 1000, pi); 

             }     
       }
```

//  }

================================================

```
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widgett);
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, widget.class);
    SimpleTimeFormat tf = new SimpleTimeFormat("$dd$ : $HH$: $mm$: $ss$");    
                String risultato = tf.format(countdown_data_fine - new Date().getTime());
                remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, titolo_puntata);
                remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2, risultato);
                manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteView);
```