# WidgetID is not adding in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a class which extends `AppWidgetProvider`, and is responsible fro showing widget. 
In my `onUpdate` method I initialize list of widgets add put all it id's in linked list.

and I also have a method `updateWidget()` which is iterate through this linked list of widgets and update it every 10 seconds.
So when I have one widget instance everything works great, but when I 'am trying to add several widget I got following problems:
To add second widget to that linked list, I need first add it, then delete it, then add it again< and only after that this widget id will be added to that linked list, so only after that it will be up-datable.

What can be the issue, how can i get a normal workflow of my widget?
Thank you on advance.

Comment: How does your list survive a power-down of the device? Consider using SharedPreferences. For multiple widgets add the widget ID as postfix to the key of preference item, you want to save.

Comment: mAppWidgetList is a member of current class, did you mean that? By the way thanks for such s quick response=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a list of widgets (mAppWidgetList) per widget. You should probably consider changing it to a static or something.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered the similar question yesterday. Please check that

[Android : Alarm for update more widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264399/android-alarm-for-update-more-widget/10265232#10265232)

You dont have to use the widget ids to update all the instances of the widget.
Use [public void updateAppWidget (ComponentName provider, RemoteViews views)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#updateAppWidget%28android.content.ComponentName,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29) to update the widget.